# how can I integrate more than 5 push certificates with Parse?

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, push

I am trying to build more than 5 apps in Parse integrating push notifications with each app. However parse is limiting push certificates to 5. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 5 push certificates per Parse app. Typically one would use separate push certificates for development and prod, and maybe a free and paid version of an app. If these are different apps, they're likely using different Parse app databases and will be able to use their own set of 5 push certificates.